# Ubuntu Freezes Up

Tags: freeze

Every time I open my VM and log into Ubuntu, the system freezes up. I am currently using Windows 11 Pro Operating system. I am experiencing many freezes up and I am using Firefox within Ubuntu to log into Nessus but I am unable to do a basic scan because Ubuntu is using too much memory and freezes up. Is there a workaround to this issue? Why is this happening?

Comment: You say Ubuntu is using too much memory. How much memory did you give it and how much swap space did you give it?

Comment: How much memory do you have, and how much memory do you allocate to the virtual machine?